# Check for pairs not having same values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have dataset in form of pandas dataframe as:

[image]

In this dataset, I want to find those names and values that have not same value. It should also work for non-square matrices. Example:

```
A to B is 4. So, B to A must be 4. But B to A is 8. 
A to C is 5. So, C to A must be 5. OK.
A to D is 8. So, D to A must be 8. But D to A is 5.
B to C is 6. So, C to B must be 6. But C to B is 3.
and so on...
```

So, want output as :

```
(A,B,4) and (B,A,8)
(A,D,8) and (D,A,5)
(B,C,6) and (C,B,3)
```

Don't print where value is same.
I am trying it using numpy array and dictionaries but can't figure out exact logic.

Comment: Some thing with `(df==df.T)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using Pandas

```
data = {'A':[0, 8,5,5,1], 'B':[4,0,3,7,2], 'C':[5,6,0,4,3], 'D':[8,9,2,0,4], 'F':[7,5,6,2,1]}
tdf = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
for idx in tdf.index:
    if idx in tdf.columns:
        for col in tdf.columns:
            if col in tdf.index and col != idx and tdf[idx][col] != tdf[col][idx]:
                print (f'({idx}, {col}, {tdf[idx][col]}) and ({col}, {idx}, {tdf[col][idx]})' )
```

tdf:

```
    A   B   C   D   F
A   0   4   5   8   7
B   8   0   6   9   5
C   5   3   0   2   6
D   5   7   4   0   2
E   1   2   3   4   1
```

and output is of the form:

```
(A, B, 8) and (B, A, 4)
(A, D, 5) and (D, A, 8)
(B, A, 4) and (A, B, 8)
(B, C, 3) and (C, B, 6)
(B, D, 7) and (D, B, 9)
(C, B, 6) and (B, C, 3)
(C, D, 4) and (D, C, 2)
(D, A, 8) and (A, D, 5)
(D, B, 9) and (B, D, 7)
(D, C, 2) and (C, D, 4)
```

Comment: I have intentionally mentioned F and E to be different. It means there can be different/additional row and columns. Your code fails on this @itprorh66.

Comment: How do you want to handle the condition when there is no col index pair to test?  Using your example, ( A , F,  7) and (?, A,  ?) given no row with index F?

Answer (score 1):

Making a dataframe thanks to what @itprorh66 has provided:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0, 8,5,5,1], 'B':[4,0,3,7,2], 'C':[5,6,0,4,3],
'D':[8,9,2,0,4], 'F':[7,5,6,2,1]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Intersect and create a square data.frame:

```
cmg = df.index.intersection(df.columns)
df = df[cmg].loc[cmg]
```

We can use the numpy upper and lower triangle functions, and pull out the indices for the upper triangle:

```
mat = df.to_numpy()
tr = np.triu_indices(len(cmg),k=1)
```

Then put everything into a dataframe, the joining of the rownames and column names is a bit unslightly, but thats the best I can do for now:

```
mat = df.to_numpy()
tr = np.triu_indices(len(cmg),k=1)
match_tri = pd.DataFrame({'i1':df.index[tr[0]] + ',' + df.columns[tr[1]],
                          'v1':mat[tr],
                          'i2':df.index[tr[1]] + ',' + df.columns[tr[0]],
                          'v2':mat.T[tr]
                         })
```

Then we just subset based on the values:

```
match_tri[match_tri.v1 != match_tri.v2]

        i1  v1  i2  v2
0   A,B 4   B,A 8
2   A,D 8   D,A 5
3   B,C 6   C,B 3
4   B,D 9   D,B 7
5   C,D 2   D,C 4
```